# Creating comments with umya spreadsheet for specific cell

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Im using umya spreadsheet to edit a xlsx file and want to add a comment with the changed cells.
I am very new to rust and it could be that i am missing something, but i cantf find a way to specify coordinate of a comment.

I am using umya spreadsheet version 0.9.1

[docs](https://docs.rs/umya-spreadsheet/latest/umya_spreadsheet/structs/struct.Comment.html)
As you can see, there is no implementation for "set_coordinate" and i am very confused as to why.
I have no problem creating and adding a comment with Comment::default(), but it only appears on A1.

Comment: `let coord = comment.get_coordinate_mut(); coord.set_col_num(12); coord.set_row_num(3);`

Comment: FYI: in the future, please include some code in your question. It's supposed to have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PitaJ why don't you post as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks, that helped, as for reproduktion, the most i coud have given you was code snippet where i invoke a not existing method.

Comment: @Luca, any code is better than nothing.

Comment: @aled if what I suggest doesn't actually work, I'd prefer it just be a comment. In this case, without much context or code, there wasn't really a way for me to test it

Answer (score 1):

The `get_coordinate_mut` method is what you're looking for. This returns a mutable reference to the coordinates, which you can use to modify the coordinates:

```rust
let coord = comment.get_coordinate_mut();
coord.set_col_num(3);
coord.set_row_num(12);

// comment is now at C12
```